# retrieving data from two tables into multidimensional array api json response

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am learning Api development where i want to retrieve data from two tables

First table (items) contains:

```
id, feed_id, title, author, content
```

Second table (feeds):

```
feed_id,title,url
```

I want to get Json response like:

```
 {
      - stories :
            [
               id
               feed_id {
                          title,
                          url
                       }
               title
               author
            ]
}
```

My PHP function to retrieve story biased on id is like:

```
$app->get('/stories/:id', 'authenticate', function($story_id) { 
    $response = array();
    $result = Database::get('db')->table('items')
    ->eq('rowid', $story_id)
    ->findOne();
    //$response["error"] = false;
    if ($result != NULL) {
    $response['stories'] = array(
        'id' => $result["id"],
        'feed_id' => $result["feed_id"],
        'title' =>  $result["title"],
        'isBreaking' => $result['isBreaking'],
        'author' => $result['author'],
        'updated' => $result["updated"],
        'url' => $result['url'],
        'content' => $result["content"]);
         echoRespnse(200, $response);
    }
    else {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "The requested resource doesn't exists";
        echoRespnse(404, $response);
    } 
});
```

The result i get is like:

```
 {
   - "stories": [
             {
                id
                feed_id
                title
                url
             }
           ]
}
```

How can i retrieve data from the second tablet (feeds) biased on feed_id and get the data into sub array?

Comment: you have mentioned two table names _stories_ and _feeds_ but in your code all I can see is one table name like _items_ . what is your query for fetching data from db?

Comment: Sorry .. first table name is items not stories ... i have corrected it

Comment: Query across a join, load data into desired data structure, JSON-encode the data structure.  Hard to give any advice beyond that, as it appers that whatever is really happening in your code here is hidden behind framework functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @MikeBrant mentioned you have to use `join` between two tables to retrieve correct data. the plain query will be something like this:

```
select items.id, items.title, items.author, items.content, feeds., feeds.title as feed_title, feeds.url from items left join feeds on items.feed_id = feeds.feed_id
```

and then change your `$response['stories']` like this:

```
$response['stories'] = array(
'id' => $result["id"],
'feed_id' => array(
  'title' => $result["feed_title"],
  'url' => $result["url"]
),
'title' =>  $result["title"],
.
.
.
);
```

you get the idea :)